# Align Euler to Vector (recreating follow path with Geo Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

Trying to make a simple follow path node setup with Geo Nodes and having issues with the Align Euler to Vector. Result should mimic the follow path (with banking and rotation) modifier.

No matter what settings I use I get weird rotations when crossing over the world X or Y axis (basically does a 360 or 720 degree rotation in a very short distance) but everything else works perfectly.

The setup is just sampling a curve and than transforming a Cubes position to sit on the curve. I then use the same position in the Align Euler to Vector and for some reasons using a second align Euler node with the Curve Tangent helps.

See node setup below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there.

Only the pivot point of the node `Align Euler to Vector` doesn't quite fit here, but if you adjust that, your object will follow the path with the correct rotation.

[image]

Here is the node group:

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! This definitely works but to get the full effect like I wanted I still needed a second align to Euler. If you for instance make the curve very tall/steep the cube is aligned in Z but its not tilted upwards as well as rotated in Z.

Comment: I got it to work by adding a second align Euler set to X and pivot auto

Comment: @GifCo Thank you for your feedback! This was unfortunately not so clear for me from the question, but I have now edited the answer so that this can be closed by you.